# Change the following client-server applications to read from file

Tags: java, sockets, networking, client-server

Currently, I have 2 applications, a client and a server the server creates a socket and the client connects to the server socket.

I'm hoping to customize the applications so that the client can type 'register' and is then requested for information required to register an account on the server.

The trouble is, I don't know where I would begin.

This is currently what I have:

Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Requester{
Socket requestSocket;
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;
String message;
Requester(){}
void run()
{
    try{
        //1. creating a socket to connect to the server
        requestSocket = new Socket("localhost", 2004);
        System.out.println("Connected to localhost in port 2004");
        //2. get Input and Output streams
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(requestSocket.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();
        in = new ObjectInputStream(requestSocket.getInputStream());
        //3: Communicating with the server
        do{
            try{
                message = (String)in.readObject();
                System.out.println("server>" + message);
                sendMessage("Hi my server");
                message = "bye";
                sendMessage(message);
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException classNot){
                System.err.println("data received in unknown format");
            }
        }while(!message.equals("bye"));
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException unknownHost){
        System.err.println("You are trying to connect to an unknown host!");
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        //4: Closing connection
        try{
            in.close();
            out.close();
            requestSocket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
void sendMessage(String msg)
{
    try{
        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("client>" + msg);
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Requester client = new Requester();
    client.run();
}
}
```

Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Provider{
ServerSocket providerSocket;
Socket connection = null;
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;
String message;
Provider(){}
void run()
{
    try{
        //1. creating a server socket
        providerSocket = new ServerSocket(2004, 10);
        //2. Wait for connection
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
        connection = providerSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        //3. get Input and Output streams
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();
        in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        sendMessage("Connection successful");
        //4. The two parts communicate via the input and output streams
        do{
            try{
                message = (String)in.readObject();
                System.out.println("client>" + message);
                if (message.equals("bye"))
                    sendMessage("bye");
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException classnot){
                System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
            }
        }while(!message.equals("bye"));
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        //4: Closing connection
        try{
            in.close();
            out.close();
            providerSocket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
void sendMessage(String msg)
{
    try{
        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("server>" + msg);
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Provider server = new Provider();
    while(true){
        server.run();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Homework? Please tag it as such if so.

Comment: Not homework, just teaching myself java in my spare time.

Comment: Teaching yourself Java, network programming, protocol design and systems design is an admirable goal.  However, you're reinventing a lot of wheels here. Even though writing code is a lot of fun, recognize that building on existing frameworks is an integral part of Software Engineering.  If your ultimate goal is to write a "real" application usable by others, your code so far indicates that you still have a lot to learn.  Nothing wrong with that, we all started completely green.  Unfortunately, SO is not a place to get tutorial-level help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question (where to begin) is that you should probably begin in the input/output loop for **both** the:

1. server, to check for receiving "register"
2. client, add a way to read input and then send it to the server

Comment: if (message.equals("register) && (signedin == false)) sendMessage("First Name?"); and then wait for input? How would I wait for input?

Comment: Excellent start for the server. It's already in a loop waiting for input (until a message with `"bye"` is received)

Comment: Thanks, my understanding of i/o is very minimum. How would I go about waiting for input from the client?

Comment: Are you talking about input **from** the client  (in the server code) or did you mean input **in** the client code? Because from the client in the server code you just handled! In the cleint you will have to learn how to read from the console using `System.in`. Use readLine for starters for example.